# How to make Firefox scrollbar thinner than "thin"

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

At Firefox 64, Mozilla introduced scrollbar-width with three possible values (auto, thin or none).  I have the following css with the scrolbar set to thin:

```
:root{
  scrollbar-color:  rgb(50,50,50) black;
  scrollbar-width: thin; }
```

When I change it to auto the thickness doesn't change -- it's the same as thin on all pages.

Is there a way to make the scrollbar less wide than "thin."  It's not very thin.  I get better response with webkit scrollbars on Chrome.

Also, how do I control the styling of the small arrows at the top and bottom of the scrollbar track?

Thanks.

Comment: this is quiet new in firefox and has very little options, how thin do you want the scrollbars ? there might be a trick with transform

Comment: About half as thin as the default thin.  Do you know any tricks with transform?

Comment: something like this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydZPrL

Comment: That looks good.  Thanks very much.  It's very helpful.